# Why is "${ARRAY[@]}" expanded into multiple words, when it's quoted?

Tags: bash, variable, bash-array

I don't understand why `"${ARRAY[@]}"` gets expanded to multiple words, when it's quoted (`"..."`)?

Take this example:

```
IFS=":" read -ra ARRAY <<< "foo:bar:baz"
for e in "${ARRAY[@]}"; do echo $e; done
foo
bar
baz
```

Any other variable that I expand in quotes, say `"${VAR}"`, results in a single word:

```
VAR="foo bar baz"
for a in "${VAR}"; do echo $a; done
foo bar baz
```

Can anyone explain this to a novice Linux user?

Comment: `${array[@]}` and `${array[*]}` are supposed to act analogously to `$@` and `$*`. That's a thing called "consistency".

Comment: The consistency extends (at least [in practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57811912/10306503)) to other forms like `"${@:2:4}"` vs. `"${array[@]:2:4}"` or `"${@/pat/repl}"` vs `"${array[@]/pat/repl}"` vs. their `*` forms.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because arrays when indexed with `@` and double quoted expand to a list of the elements. It's documented in `man bash` under "Arrays":

> If  the word is double-quoted, ...  `${name[@]}` expands each element
> of name to a separate word.

This behaviour is required if you don't want each element to be subject to word splitting on $IFS characters and globbing (i.e. expansion of `*`, `?`, or `[...]`).

```
#!/bin/bash
arr=(a 'b c' d)
for el in  ${arr[@]}  ; do echo "1: $el" ; done
for el in "${arr[@]}" ; do echo "2: $el" ; done
```

Output:

```
1: a
1: b
1: c
1: d
2: a
2: b c
2: d
```

If you want the array expanded as a single string (with the elements of the array delimited by the first character of `$IFS`, by default a space), then use `"${arr[*]}"`.

The `"${arr[@]}"` and `"${arr[*]}"` syntax for array expansion is analogous to `"$@"` and `"$*"` for the positional parameters.

Comment: It's not really *whitespace*, it's characters of `$IFS` (SPC, TAB, NL by default) and wildcard characters. IMO, the wording is a bit misleading here. It's not *useful* it's *required*. You don't leave parameter expansions unquoted unless you want that split+glob. Split+glob on an array hardly ever makes sense, so array expansions should almost always be quoted.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Updated.

Comment: That *This behaviour is required if an element contains whitespace or characters from the $IFS variable* wording still doesn't make much sense. Maybe something like *Without the quoting, each element would also be subject to split+glob so not do what you want if they contained characters of `$IFS` (not whitespace) or glob operators such as `*`, `?` or `[...]`*.