# Prevent splitting command line argument at spaces when running in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, escape-characters, variable-substitution

I'm trying to run a command in a bash variable, like this:

```bash
cmd="python -m mymodule 'argument 123 456' argument2=32 argument3=234"
$cmd
```

It looks like it is splitting the command line arguments in the first string even though it is surrounded with single quotes:

```
['argument', '123', '456', 'argument2=32', 'argument3=234']
```

Is there anything I can do to prevent this? I've tried to use esacped double-quotes `\"`, backticks `` ` ``, but nothing works, it will still split the first command line argument on the spaces.

Comment: Don't put the command in a variable; variables are for data, not shell syntax and executable code. If you need to store a command, use a function (that's what they're for) or possibly an array. See [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) and many previous questions (but ignore anything involving `eval` -- it is a massive bug magnet).

Comment: @GordonDavisson The same thing will happen if I put the arguments in an arg variable, `arg="'argument 123 456' argument2=32 argument3=234"` and run with `python -m mymodule $arg`

Comment: Well yes, that's the same issue just without the command itself

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would recommend storing the command and its arguments in an array:

```bash
cmd=( "python" "-m" "mymodule" "argument 123 456" "argument2=32" "argument3=324" )
```

and running it as

```
"${cmd[@]}"
```

- The key is dereferencing the array content as `${cmd[@]}` with an `@`, and placing it in double-quotes, because the shell will then expand this to a list of array elements in a way as if each element were double-quoted, thereby preventing word-splitting (see e.g. [this related Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/562659/377345) for more on that).
- At the same time, you must add each token that the shell is to treat separately as its own array element (so e.g. `"-m"` and `"mymodule"` must be separate elements - stating it as `"-m mymodule"` will likely fail, being mis-interpreted as either a value-less option `m mymodule` or an option `m` with value  `mymodule` including the leading space - see [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/667139/377345) for more insight).